# How to add Hyperlink on php/html table that displays information from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MYSQL table:

```
+----------+---------+------+--------------+
| name     | cost    | life | whenacquired |
+----------+---------+------+--------------+
| aardvark | 2500.00 |    5 | 2012-01-01   |
| bobcat   | 2000.00 |    4 | 2012-03-01   |
| cougar   | 3000.00 |    6 | 2013-01-01   |
| deer     | 5000.00 |    4 | 2010-01-01   |
| eagle    | 2000.00 |    3 | 2009-01-01   |
+----------+---------+------+--------------+
```

where I have written a php script to read from the MySQL db:

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM animals");

 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>name</th>
 </tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }

echo "</table>";

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

which produces:

```
    +----------+
    | name     |
    +----------+
    | aardvark |
    | bobcat   |
    | cougar   |
    | deer     |
    | eagle    |
    +----------+
```

to display the name, however I want the `name` to be a hyperlink which when clicked brings up the corresponding data, example: when `aardvark` is clicked, the following information will pop up

```
    +----------+---------+------+--------------+
    | name     | cost    | life | whenacquired |
    +----------+---------+------+--------------+
    | aardvark | 2500.00 |    5 | 2012-01-01   |
    +----------+---------+------+--------------+
```

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such.

Comment: @SuperDJ That was a small typo, thanks for pointing it out however

Comment: Okay? So what have you tried so far? Make the "aardvark" a `<button>` with whatever styling you want, a click handler that takes the aardvark's row and shows it in a modal or something, and done. But why show the data that you already have right there?

Comment: Sorry I was just typing away, please review the question I had just edited

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry I was just typing away, please review the question I had just edited

Comment: @John Conde Sorry I was just typing away, please review the question I had just edited

Comment: You'll need to add a corresponding column that will have/hold the respective links for each of your data, unless you want a generic link.

Comment: Wow, and because I am trying my best at a problem I am voted down 4 times, obviously if I knew the answer it wouldn't have been asked, pointing out the errors so I can simply correct them would have been more ethical than down voting my 'silly question'

Comment: it's not about whether you know the answer - posting before all the details are in, especially without showing what you've already tried to make it do something (googling for onclick tutorials is very easy for instance) means that the thousands of people browsing Stackoverflow *per second* will see an incomplete post, downvote it, and move on to the next question in their queue. The only one to blame there is the person who posted before they were done writing it up =)

Comment: So, have you tried the answer given below? @dames

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I am working on it at the moment, having small errors, but trying to resolve them before accepting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use css/javascript to do this.

There are 3 ways: The more easy way is to print all data, but just not displaying it yet until someone clicks the link. For the hyperlink part. In this example I used a 'span' element which is styled like a hyperlink.

```
//place inside your head tag
<style>
.hyperlink-lookalike
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
<script>
//javascript function to toggle extra animal info
function show_extra_info(id)
{
   var tr = document.getElementById('extra_info_'+id);
   if(tr.style.display=='none')
   {
      tr.style.display='table-row';
   }
   else{
      tr.style.display='none';
   }
}
</script>

//inside the loop
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td colspan='2'><span class="hyperlink-lookalike" onclick="show_extra_info(' . $row['id'] . ')">' . $row['name'] . '</span></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr id="extra_info_' . $row['id'] . '" style="display:none;">';
echo '<td>' . $row['cost'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['life'] . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

The second way is, and this one uses a hyperlink, go to a detail view:

```
echo '<td><a href="http://www.example.com/animaldetailedinfo.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a></td>';
```

The third (more advanced) way is to do an AJAX request to get the information and display that in a 'div' tag. For that you might want to use a javascript library like jquery. Again if you want it to show up in a popup a hyperlink is not necessary. A span element with an onclick event that fires a javascript function that does the request to the server for more information is easier.

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/animaldetailedinfo.php", function( data ) {
  $( "#popupcontainer" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: Where/how does the hyperlink `href` come into play? OP: *"however I want the name to be a hyperlink which when clicked brings up the corresponding data"*

Comment: don't give that span inline style, make it a class and stick it in a stylesheet or `<style>` element. Especially as an answer, it's worth showing how to do it right from the get-go

Comment: edited my answer with according to comments of Fred and Mike. Have fun coding!